# Best Practice to adjust height of Material UI Icon

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I put two icons from Material UI Icons in a row. The heights themselves are same: 24px. But the height of path is different. One is 18px and the other is 22px. They don't look cool.

How can I adjust the height? I mean "the height that users see".

```js
import {
  Delete,
  FileCopy
} from "@material-ui/icons";

...

<Box display="flex">
  <FileCopy onClick={handleCopy} />
  <Delete onClick={handleDelete} />
</Box>
```

I tried setting the the height of SVG, it made vertical align ugly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The icons have a `fontSize` property - e.g. `<HomeIcon fontSize="large" />`.

You can also set it explicitly - `<DeleteIcon style={{fontSize: "10px"}}/>`.

Comment: So, I'll calculate the height and set the margin to align...

Answer (score 1):

It's tough to answer this question without more context of the components and what you can pass to them and what is being returned from them.

Assuming `<FileCopy />` is returning an `SVG` element that you can pass valid svg properties to, the correct way to adjust the size would be to pass it height and width attributes.

```
<FileCopy height='48' width='48' />
```

Another way to think about this is the svgs likely have a `viewBox` that acts as a canvas. The height and width properties of the svg will change the size of the viewBox/canvas with the icon/paths inside it scaling along with it.

```html
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" height='24' width='24'><circle fill="#FF4500" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/><path fill="#FFF" d="M16.67 10a1.46 1.46 0 00-2.47-1 7.12 7.12 0 00-3.85-1.23L11 4.65l2.14.45a1 1 0 10.13-.61L10.82 4a.31.31 0 00-.37.24l-.74 3.47a7.14 7.14 0 00-3.9 1.23 1.46 1.46 0 10-1.61 2.39 2.87 2.87 0 000 .44c0 2.24 2.61 4.06 5.83 4.06s5.83-1.82 5.83-4.06a2.87 2.87 0 000-.44 1.46 1.46 0 00.81-1.33zm-10 1a1 1 0 111 1 1 1 0 01-1-1zm5.81 2.75a3.84 3.84 0 01-2.47.77 3.84 3.84 0 01-2.47-.77.27.27 0 01.38-.38A3.27 3.27 0 0010 14a3.28 3.28 0 002.09-.61.27.27 0 11.39.4zm-.18-1.71a1 1 0 111-1 1 1 0 01-1.01 1.04z"/></svg>
</div>
<div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" height='48' width='48'><circle fill="#FF4500" cx="10" cy="10" r="10"/><path fill="#FFF" d="M16.67 10a1.46 1.46 0 00-2.47-1 7.12 7.12 0 00-3.85-1.23L11 4.65l2.14.45a1 1 0 10.13-.61L10.82 4a.31.31 0 00-.37.24l-.74 3.47a7.14 7.14 0 00-3.9 1.23 1.46 1.46 0 10-1.61 2.39 2.87 2.87 0 000 .44c0 2.24 2.61 4.06 5.83 4.06s5.83-1.82 5.83-4.06a2.87 2.87 0 000-.44 1.46 1.46 0 00.81-1.33zm-10 1a1 1 0 111 1 1 1 0 01-1-1zm5.81 2.75a3.84 3.84 0 01-2.47.77 3.84 3.84 0 01-2.47-.77.27.27 0 01.38-.38A3.27 3.27 0 0010 14a3.28 3.28 0 002.09-.61.27.27 0 11.39.4zm-.18-1.71a1 1 0 111-1 1 1 0 01-1.01 1.04z"/></svg>
</div>
```